# Failed to build module from its module interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift5, xcode12

I have added a third party pod to my project. While i can build the app just fine in Debug target. As soon as i try to build my project with release target i get this build error.

`Failed to build module 'XXXX' from its module interface; the compiler that produced it, 'Apple Swift version 5.2.4 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.9 clang-1103.0.32.53)', may have used features that aren't supported by this compiler, 'Apple Swift version 5.4 (swiftlang-1205.0.26.9 clang-1205.0.19.55)'`

I am not sure why it is only giving this problem with Release target and not with Debug target.

Any kind of help here would be really helpful. I am using Xcode 12.5